# Plugin: Unable to Save the Image Alignment Option to Display in the Widget in the Sidebar

Tags: plugins, widgets

I am trying to add a select option to help user align the gravatar image. The problem is all value are saved except for the Image Alignment. When they select Image Alignment, it will revert back to "None"

http://pastebin.com/03fj7tc6

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Hi JPL, if you really want someone helps you, try to extract the *relevant part* of your code and put it in the question body. If you link all that code in an external site, I bet no one will read it all and so no one can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the update() function, you need to modify

```
$instance['image_alignment'] = isset($new_instance['image_alignment'] );
```

to

```
$instance['image_alignment'] = $new_instance['image_alignment'];
```

`isset()` is making the variable boolean, while you are expecting string.

Comment: Thanks man it works, my last problem is calling the wordpress default CSS class when the image_alignment applies. I added this line which call the avatar

  http://pastebin.com/DtnGXk6Y

but no changes happen

Comment: You should wrap the avatar within a span or div and apply the alignment on the element. get_avatar doesn't allow styling arguments. check the [get_avatar() function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar)

Comment: Thanks i tried adding  a class but I got a parse weird error
http://pastebin.com/63S8drq3
i tried adding ?> after echo  and <?php after div but still the same

Comment: I also tried adding a filter and i get this error http://192.185.107.164/~jefreyla/
code reference
http://pastebin.com/v6PGfW6C